# Spontaneous Swift Compiler Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, swift

My project had zero errors/warning from Xcode 6 Beta 1 - Xcode 6 Beta 6. When I updated to Beta 7, Xcode started telling me I have about 170 errors in my project. Mainly SpriteKit methods/objects/properties. It is still giving me the errors on the actual release of Xcode 6. I know these things shouldn't be a problem, because I have had absolutely no trouble building in the past with the exact same code. To give an example:

[image]

This kind of stuff is happening all over my project. I have uninstalled/reinstalled the Xcode Betas, as well as the release several times, but to no avail. This is my biggest project yet, and I'm incredibly upset that I can't figure this out. I would hate to have to rewrite my whole project in Objective-C. I called Apple developer support, and the only things they could recommend I had already tried and they didn't work. I also can't seem to find anyone else having similar problems online.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I bet it's about implicitly unwrapped optionals turned into "normal" optionals.

Try appending the implicitly unwrapped optional operator `!` in each line where `physicalBody` is referenced, such as:

```
blockSprite.physicalBody!.categoryBitMask = ...
```

If that actually solves the problem, then for safer code I suggest you to assign the new instance of `SKPhysicalBody` to a variable, do all the initialization, then assign the variable to `blockSprite.physicalBody`. That way you don't have to deal with optionals.

As a general rule, even if you are 100% sure an optional contains a non nil value, it's always better to avoid implicitly unwrapped optionals - less headaches at runtime, if it happens that an unwrapped variable is actually nil.

Comment: After adding the implicitly unwrapped optional operator to a few places and building again, I received the same error on those lines.

Comment: Can you post the modified code? Either in your question, or in a gist (or similar)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `physicsBody` property of `SKNode` is now an Optional. The easiest fix for this will be to create an `SKPhysicsBody` instance, configure it, and then assign it to your node:

```
let blockSprite = SKSpriteNode(...)
blockSprite.position = ...
// etc
let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: blockSprite.size)
physicsBody.categoryBitMask = ContactCategory.block
// etc
blockSprite.physicsBody = physicsBody
```